# Why does my application hang while updating database records?

Tags: c#, winforms

The following application code hangs while updating database records.
It only displays 0 in output screen, and program hangs forever.
However there are more than 50,000 records in table.
(The program converts ISCII codes to UNICODE and writes them back into the database.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace demoupdateform
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test1.txt");

    String[,] harltabcol = new String[,]
        {
            {"Col_name","Table_name"}

        };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Password=admin;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=DEEPAK-87E8B4");
        SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection("Password=admin;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=DEEPAK-87E8B4");



        string temp;
        string temp1;
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < harltabcol.GetLength(0); i++)
            {

                    cn.Open();


                SqlCommand cmdSel = new SqlCommand( "select [" + harltabcol[i, 0] + "] from [" + harltabcol[i, 1] + "]",cn);
                //cn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmdSel.ExecuteReader();
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                int j = 0;
                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    temp = (rdr[harltabcol[i, 0]].ToString()).ToString();

                    temp1 = (Iscii2Unicode(temp)).ToString();
                    SqlCommand cmdUpd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [" + harltabcol[i,1] + "] SET [" + harltabcol[i,0] + "] =N'"+temp1+"' WHERE " + harltabcol[i,0] + "='" + temp + "'",cn1);
                    temp = rdr[harltabcol[i, 0]].ToString();
                    cn1.Open();
                    cmdUpd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine(j++);
                    file.WriteLine(temp+" --> "+temp1);
                    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;

                    if (progressBar1.Value == 99)
                        progressBar1.Value = 0;

                    cmdUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    temp = null;
                    temp1 = null;
                    cn1.Close();
                }
                progressBar1.Value = 100;
                cn.Close(); 
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured " + ex.ToString());
        }


    }
    public string Iscii2Unicode(string IsciiStr)
    {
        Encoding EncFrom = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        Encoding EncTo = Encoding.GetEncoding(57002);
        Byte[] b = EncFrom.GetBytes(IsciiStr);

        return EncTo.GetString(b);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Normal. You don't give the message loop a chance to run. Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to process your DB queries and call [ProgressChanged](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar) to update the GUI.

Comment: A good resource on [WinForms Threading](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml), particularly the parts about the UI thread. That should help you understand _why_ it is hanging and why Serge's answer fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you hit the database inside `while` loop, that cause your program hung. So you can create a big `update` query and call `Command.Execute` once. this may not be the best solution but it will save the time of opening and closing database connection for each iteration.

```
StringBuilder updateQuery = new StringBuilder("");
while (rdr.Read())
{
   temp = (rdr[harltabcol[i, 0]].ToString()).ToString();
   temp1 = (Iscii2Unicode(temp)).ToString();
   updateQuery.Append("UPDATE [" + harltabcol[i,1] + "] SET [" + harltabcol[i,0] + "] =N'"+temp1+"' WHERE " + harltabcol[i,0] + "='" + temp + "';");
} 
SqlCommand cmdUpd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery.ToString(),cn1);
cn1.Open();
cmdUpd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmdUpd.ExecuteNonQuery();
temp = null;
temp1 = null;
cn1.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: Bu connection cn and cn1 must be opened before while loop, and read&update shall be run in the loop, after loop cn and cn1 must be closed